# VF TabPanel activeTabClass and disabledTabClass not working

Tags: tabpanel, style, force, visual

Using the attached example code, none of the classes seem to work.

If I look carefully when the page loads the TABS are coloured but then some code or SF style sheets switches my tab colours off.

I have removed all my other code to ensure it was nothing I was doing - which leaves me with the example below.

Is this a SFDC bug ? Can anyone see anything wrong with my implementation?

Note : I am going to list my code in a reply to this post as it seems this RT edit is not able to display my code without messing it up :-(

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false">
    <apex:tabPanel activeTabClass="ActiveTab" disabledTabClass="LockedTab" inactiveTabClass="InactiveTab"   >

            <apex:tab label="Tab1" name="name1" >
                xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            </apex:tab>

            <apex:tab label="Tab2" name="name2"  >
                yyyyyyyyyyyyyy      
            </apex:tab>

            <apex:tab label="Tab3" name="name3" disabled="true">
                zzzzzzzz
            </apex:tab>

    </apex:tabPanel>

<style>
.ActiveTab{background-color:rgb(70,193,232);}

.InactiveTab{background-color:rgb(255,0,0);}

.LockedTab{background-color:rgb(0,237,0);}
</style>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: from inspect element you can easily find which file or css are overriding your css. Please check there.